# Cloudfront not serving content from Edge location. It is hitting origin server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have setup cloud-front to serve cache content from edge locations.but my cloudfront is not serving cache content from edge location, it is hitting origin server for all request.

below is the screenshot of my cloudfront setting.

[image]

Are my settings correct?

*******************************edited***********************

Trying to assign cname but its not working. am i doing something wrong??

[image]

Comment: How do you know Cloudfront is hitting the Origin server and not the cloud front?

Comment: i am checking the log of my application server and in the log i can see the request hitting to my server.

Comment: Can you share the link of your application? And another question is does does your log shows combination of same IP address or all the IP address are different? As per your Cloudfront setting all seems to be correct.

Comment: http://dh7jv4lqr6tiu.cloudfront.net/ - cloudfront link  and web application direct access link without cloudfront is http://54.218.54.243:3000/

Answer (score 0):

You should add a C-Name to your application domain to point to "dh7jv4lqr6tiu.cloudfront.net". Then your application will be serving from the Cloud Front. The Cloud Front Settings are correct.

Comment: How to add cname to point to "dh7jv4lqr6tiu.cloudfront.net" ?? can you provide a link??

Comment: Where is your Application Domain DNS? Eg Godaddy, AWS Route 53

Comment: I am not using godaddy.  I have launched aws instance and got ec2-54-218-54-243.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com public DNS.

Comment: So if you want your application to serve the cloud front you need to assign it a domain and point that domain to the Cloudfront using the C-name

Comment: I have assign "SANJAYSALUNKHE.COM" domain to my application , but i am not able to point it to "dh7jv4lqr6tiu.cloudfront.net" domain using godaddy CNAME.  see the edited question . i have attached screenshot where i tried to assign cname.

Comment: Change that "A-Host" in first dropdown to C-name and it will work.